# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>when using Nest to search a text

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am having a code error *"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable"*  when trying to use Nest to search a text

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
            .DefaultIndex("my_index");

        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var text = "testinsg, test, my testing";
        var analyzeResponse = client.Indices.Analyze(new AnalyzeRequest
        {
            // error occurred here when trying to pass the value of the variable text
            Text = text,
            Analyzer = "standard",
            Tokenizer = "standard"
        });
        var stemmedWords = analyzeResponse.Tokens.Select(t => t.Token);
        var stemCounts = stemmedWords
            .GroupBy(w => new Stemmer().Stem(w))
            .Select(g => new { Stem = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
        foreach (var stemCount in stemCounts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Stem: {stemCount.Stem}, Count: {stemCount.Count}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line is that?

Comment: @GSerg Text = text,

Comment: So the `AnalyzeRequest` object has a property `IEnumerable<string> Text {get;set;}`, and you are trying to assign a `string` to that.

Comment: I am trying to Nest to search for a text I have not use it before  how can I convert the text

Comment: @GSerg yes AnalyzeRequest object has a property public IEnumerable<string> Text { get; set; } but cannot be changed because its Nuget package I downloaded

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `Text` is `IEnumerable<string>` so just wrap the string into collection, for example array:

```cs
new AnalyzeRequest
{
    Text = new [] {text},
    // ...
}
```